# Bypassing SSL pinning Using Frida issue

Tags: tls, penetration-test, android

I am a penetration tester, and I was doing some SSL pinning bypass using Frida.

I have pushed all the required files and certificates, and burp is intercepting traffic from the Android Studio emulator.

I have performed the steps to run frida.

```
[Android Emulator 5554::com.*****.**** ( flagged for ethical security reasons )]->
[.] Cert Pinning Bypass/Re-Pinning
[+] Loading our CA...
[o] Our CA Info: CN=PortSwigger CA, OU=PortSwigger CA, O=PortSwigger, L=PortSwigger, ST=PortSwigger, C=PortSwigger
[+] Creating a KeyStore for our CA...
[+] Creating a TrustManager that trusts the CA in our KeyStore...
[+] Our TrustManager is ready...
[+] Hijacking SSLContext methods now...
[-] Waiting for the app to invoke SSLContext.init()...
```

And when I try to interact with the application, the application is not allowing my request through because of the missing certificate and frida is not capturing the request and bypassing the pinning knowing that I have performed all the right steps.

I am here if anyone needs to ask more question .. can you please help with the above ?

Comment: You wrote that you have performed the steps to run Frida. Can you provide more details? e.g., you started Frida server on the emulator, then you ran a script to hook a certain method, etc.?

Comment: Also, this part is not clear: "the application is not allowing my request through because of the missing certificate and frida is not capturing the request and bypassing the pinning knowing that I have performed all the right steps". Do you mean you bypassed the pinning once before, so Frida is not capturing the request? What would be the logical justification for that?

Comment: Hello @auspicious99 
`adb push frida-server /data/local/tmp/
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/frida-server
adb push C:\Users\hacho\Downloads\cert-der.crt /data/local/tmp/cert-der.crt
adb push C:\Users\hacho\Desktop\platform-tools\fridascript.js /data/local/tmp
adb shell /data/local/tmp/frida-server &

frida -U -f com.*****.*****  -l C:\Users\hacho\Desktop\platform-tools\fridascript.js --no-paus `

Comment: basically i did exactly as this link shows https://medium.com/@ved_wayal/hail-frida-the-universal-ssl-pinning-bypass-for-android-e9e1d733d29

Comment: Looks like the app may not be invoking SSLContext.init(). Are you sure the app is calling SSLContext.init() ?

Comment: Assuming it is doing certificate pinning, it may be using a different way. Have you tried https://codeshare.frida.re/@akabe1/frida-multiple-unpinning/ ?

Comment: was there any solution for this?